# Missing server tags after Generate Local Resources

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, resources

I generated local resources for my page by "`Generate Local Resources`" tool in `VS2010`. VS add meta-resource key for all control which have property like Text or ToolTip. Everything is great.

But I have in my aspx code server tags `<% if(condition) { %> my aspx code <% { %>` which were removed. Why? Now I have to manually compare files after and before generation. Have you any idea how to avoid this?

Comment: I also get this with <%= ... %> code. And others have reported it removing the BehaviourID tag from controls.

Comment: I encountered this issue using VS2012 here too. Generate local resources removed the markup inside a asp:content control.

Answer (score 0):

Generate local resources works static control or value . if you want to dynamic content or extendent condition(s) use  **Resource-Provider Model** or maybe you can use literal.